# Windows Phone 8 - Playing streamed audio (internet radio station)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, audio-streaming, background-audio

I am trying to make an application that would play an audio stream (mp3) from the following URL http://icecast6.play.cz/radio1-128.mp3. I am struggling to get it working. Is there any default support for cases like these? That the content is continuously streamed?

I have tried to use **Background Audio Agent** and set **Media Element** but none of that has been working for me. Would **Background Audio Streamer** be an option for me? I would be happy for any similar example that I would use to my advantage.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I found phonesm project on codeplex](http://phonesm.codeplex.com/) that provides great examples and functionality for implementing internet audio streaming.

Comment: how to use it in my windows phone silverlight8.1 app?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use BackgroundAudioPlayer by creating another project and adding its reference to your project.

Check this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: Hey Vits, that was the first approach I took but it does not work by default for audio streaming (audio that is constantly streamed at one location). Or did I miss some setting that will enable this?

Comment: [Download Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Background-Audio-Player-b5f70b13/file/86859/2/Background%20Audio%20Player%20Sample.zip).it will clear your ideas.you just need to pass your url to create Uri for BAckgroundAudioPlayer.

Comment: Hello, it does not work for me. I changed the URL in the example. Please note that I am talking about AUDIO STREAMING, not audio file placed on remote server. If you open the file you will see that it is a continuous stream from a radio. Thank you

Comment: oh..oh..got your point.it is not a mp3 file.So in this case you need to use AudioStreamingAgent.

check this sample it will definitely guide you [Download sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Background-Audio-Streamer-e85b8deb/file/62717/12/Background%20Audio%20Streamer%20Sample.zip)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft player framework.

For more details [Player Framework](https://playerframework.codeplex.com/)