# Playing online radio using BackgroundAudioPlayer on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I want to play songs from a online radio and for that i am using the BackgroundAudioPlayer for windows phone 8. Now i downloaded the sample app provided by MS and modified that a bit primarily to test whether the streaming link is working or not. So, my new AudioTrack object is looked like this one,

```
 new AudioTrack(new Uri("http://live.abcradiobd.fm:8282/;listen.mp3", UriKind.Absolute), 
                        "ABC Radio", 
                        string.Empty, 
                        string.Empty,
                        null)
```

This is not working at all. After sometimes it generates TimeOutException but the link is perfectly working in VLC player and other audio player out there.Any solution?

**Solved:**

Tried [Phonesm](http://phonesm.codeplex.com/) and it's working perfectly. You can use that for both audio and video streaming. But before building that project make sure that you have downloaded the correct version for MPPF which is v1.2 from [here](http://playerframework.codeplex.com/releases/view/105214) and install as an extension to visual studio.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541390/windows-phone-8-playing-streamed-audio-internet-radio-station?rq=1

Comment: @Kulasangar Yap,Thank you for suggestion. Finally able to do some audio streaming :) 

But there is an issue regarding using Phonesm. Before building that project, we have to download correct MPPF version (v1.2- not the latest one) from [link](http://playerframework.codeplex.com/releases/view/105214) and then you can use that. Otherwise you will get error.